# Hello l want to make a spawner in godot but the sponer didn't want to spawn anything and it show me this massage

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, godot4

Hello l want to make a spawner in godot but the sponer didn't want to spawn anything and it show me this massage.

```
E 0:00:02.270   emit_signal: Error calling method from signal 'timeout': 'Node2D(cloud spowner.gd)::_on_cloud_spowner_timeout': Method not found..
  <C++ Source>  core/object.cpp:1242 @ emit_signal()
```

```
l want to make spawner
```

Answer (score 0):

whats the rest of the script, it is saying it cant find a function to call, so either its miss spelled or not being instanced correctly.